# General Solution to External Force with Damping (Synergetics by Haken Self-Organization)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In Chapter 7 Section 1 of Hermann Haken's textbook *Synergetic* we are given a differential equation of the form:

$$ \dot{q}=-\gamma q + F(t)$$

where $\gamma > 0$ can be interpreted as a damping constant and $F(t)$ can be interpreted as an external force applied to the system. It is then claimed without justification that the solution to this differential equations is

$$q(t)=\int_0^t e^{-\gamma(t-\tau)}F(\tau)d\tau$$

In order to show this is true I considered just taking the derivative of $q(t)$ with respect to time and verifying that it indeed satisfies the differential equation. A naive application of The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is apparently inappropriate here (I believe because the integrand depends on both $t$ and $\tau$?).

What is a proper way to show that this indeed is a solution to the differential equation? My postdoc said this has something to do with exponential smoothing and moving averages, so bonus points if you can clarify that connection. :)

Thanks!

Comment: The integrand depends only on $\tau$ not on $t$

Comment: When applied the fundamental theorem of calculus yields $\dot{q}=F(t)$ so if this is true, I don't understand why The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is failing...

Comment: the exponential with the t variable can be put outside the integrand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dot q+\gamma q=F(t)\implies\\
e^{\gamma t}\dot q+\gamma e^{\gamma t} q=F(t)e^{\gamma t}\implies\\
(e^{\gamma t}q)^\cdot=F(t)e^{\gamma t}\implies\\
e^{\gamma t}q(t)-q(0)=\int_0^t F(\tau)e^{\gamma \tau}d\tau\implies\\
q(t)=q(0)e^{-\gamma t}+e^{-\gamma t}\int_0^tF(\tau)e^{\gamma \tau}d\tau.
$$

(To see how you can directly check you solution see [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule))